How to break/stack the phrase "도박을 멈출 수없으신가요?"
I work for a non-profit making posters for gambling addiction help, along with poster translations. We had to remove some imagery from the posters, so now the text needs to take up the majority of the space. How do I:

Translate "Can't stop betting nonstop?" into Korean, or closest possible?
Break the lines safety without changing the meaning?

I need it to be compact and vaguely square proportionally.
I have tried:
"도박을 멈출 수
없으신가요?"
But I think that changes the meaning, and frankly needs to be broken into another line.
Thanks!

수없으신가요 is really a mis-spelling of 수 없으신가요.


Translating "Can't stop betting nonstop?" to Korean can be quite subjective, since a meaning-to-meaning translation is needed to save the nuance.  For instance, "betting nonstop" can be translated to "못 멈추는 도박" (or "멈추지 못하는 도박", if preferred), and "Can't stop" can be translated to "멈출 수 없으신가요?" to maintain the rhyme of the original sentence.  Since this is for a poster, it is more natural to omit the particle "을".  So "못 멈추는 도박, 멈출 수 없으신가요?" works well.  However, it's worth noting that other translations might be better, as the current version is a bit lengthy and some word choices could be improved.
In Korean, the meaning of a sentence typically does not change based on spaces or line breaks (spaces in Korean documents were first introduced in 1877, which is relatively recent).  Although "수없으신가요" should be written as "수 없으신가요" according to current standards. This is because "수" and "없다" are considered separate words. Therefore placing a line break between "수" and "없" is correct.

Some suggestions:
못 멈추는 도박,
멈출 수 없으신가요?

멈추지 못하는
도박, 멈출 수
없으신가요?


Thank you! Your second suggestion probably will work.
